# Bug 2 Modal same page don't send the email

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a site that has two different modals and is working (open modal, select the correct modal, validation etc). The real problem is the message is not coming to my email. If I comment the first modal on the code, the second modal sends the message (it's not a problem with the PHP and Jquery validation). So I think its a conflict with the code between the two modals.

Button 1:

```
<div class="btn-produtos simule"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn border-produtos btn-lg" data-remote="false" data-whatever="Hospitais" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Faça sua cotação </a><i class="icon-check"> </i></div>
```

Button 2:

```
<div class="btn-produtos simule"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn border-produtos btn-lg" data-remote="false" data-whatever="Cirurgia Segura" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Simule e Contrate </a><i class="icon-check"> </i></div>
```

Modal 1:

```
<!-- BEGIN MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm3" method="post" novalidate>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Tipo de seguro</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="seguro" disabled>
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Nome<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Digite seu nome.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Email<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Digite seu email.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 controls">
                            <label>Telefone</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone">
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 controls">
                            <label>Valor do plano</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="plano" required data-validation-required-message="Escolha seu plano.">
                                <option value="">Selecione seu Plano</option>
                                <option>500 mil</option>
                                <option>700 mil</option>
                                <option>1 milhão</option>
                                <option>Até 5 milhões</option>
                            </select>
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                            <label>Mensagem<span>*</span></label>
                            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Digite sua mensagem."></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme-bg btn-lg">Enviar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END MODAL -->
```

Modal 2:

```
<!-- BEGIN MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form name="sentMessage" id="csForm" method="post" novalidate>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="row control-group text-center">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <a href="regulamento-cirurgia-segura-segpro.pdf" target="_blank"><button type="button" class="btn btn-theme-bg btn-lg text-center">Ver Regulamento</button></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <h3>Dados do Médico</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm controls">
                                    <label>Nome Completo<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Digite seu nome.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>CPF<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control cpf" id="cpf" required data-validation-required-message="Digite seu CPF." minlength="14"  data-validation-minlength-message="Digite seu CPF corretamente.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>CRM<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="crm" required data-validation-required-message="Digite seu CRM.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Email<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Digite seu email.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Telefone<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control phone" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Digite seu telefone." minlength="14" data-validation-minlength-message="Digite seu telefone corretamente.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Especialidade<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="especialidade" required data-validation-required-message="Digite sua especialidade.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <h3>Dados do Paciente</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Nome Completo<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name2" required data-validation-required-message="Digite o nome.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>CPF<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control cpf" id="cpf2" required data-validation-required-message="Digite o CPF." minlength="14"  data-validation-minlength-message="Digite o CPF corretamente.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>RG<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rg" required data-validation-required-message="Digite o RG.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Sexo<span>*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="sexo" required data-validation-required-message="Escolha o gênero.">
                                        <option value="">Selecione o gênero</option>
                                        <option>Masculino</option>
                                        <option>Feminino</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Idade<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="idade" required data-validation-required-message="Digite a idade.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Altura<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control valor" id="altura" required data-validation-required-message="Digite a altura." maxlength="4">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Peso<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="peso" required data-validation-required-message="Digite o peso.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>IMC</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="imc" disabled="disabled" required max="38" data-validation-required-message="Campo automático obrigatório." data-validation-max-message="O IMC não pode ser maior que 38.">
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Email<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email2" required data-validation-required-message="Digite o email.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Telefone<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control phone" id="phone2" required data-validation-required-message="Digite o telefone." minlength="14"  data-validation-minlength-message="Digite o telefone corretamente.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Pagar com boleto<span>*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="boleto" required data-validation-required-message="Escolha o pagamento.">
                                        <option value="">Selecione o pagamento</option>
                                        <option>Sim</option>
                                        <option>Não</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <h3>Dados da Cirurgia</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Cirurgia<span>*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="cirurgia" required data-validation-required-message="Escolha a cirurgia." multiple title="Selecione a Cirurgia" data-selected-text-format="count > 3">
                                        <!-- <option value="">Selecione a Cirurgia</option> -->
                                        <option>Abdominoplastia </option>
                                        <option>Blefaroplastia </option>
                                        <option>Dermolipectomia </option>
                                        <option>Implante Capilar </option>
                                        <option>Lipoaspiração </option>
                                        <option>Lipoescultura </option>
                                        <option>Lifting </option>
                                        <option>Mastopexia </option>
                                        <option>Mamoplastia de Aumento </option>
                                        <option>Mamoplastia Redutora </option>
                                        <option>Rinoplastia </option>
                                        <option>Rinoseptoplastia </option>
                                        <option>Outros </option>
                                    </select>
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Clínica ou Hospital<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hospital" required data-validation-required-message="Digite a Clínica ou Hospital.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>UTI<span>*</span></label>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="uti" required data-validation-required-message="Escolha se terá UTI.">
                                        <option value="">Selecione a opção</option>
                                        <option>Sim</option>
                                        <option>Não</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Data da Cirurgia<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control data" id="data" required data-validation-required-message="Digite a data." minlength="10"  data-validation-minlength-message="Digite a data corretamente.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Valor Total da Cirurgia<span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control valor" id="valorc" name="data[valor_cirurgia]" required data-validation-required-message="Digite o valor.">
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <label>Valor a Pagar</label>
                                    <p id="valor_apagar">0,00</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                            <div class="row control-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="termos" required data-validation-required-message="Você deve aceitar os termos antes de continuar"> Li e aceito o <a href="regulamento-cirurgia-segura-segpro.pdf" target="_blank">Regulamento</a> apresentado
                                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme-bg btn-lg">Finalizar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="success2"></div>
</div>
<!-- END MODAL -->
```

I tried a lot of things but have not had success unless I deleted the first Modal.

I changed the ids of the modals and nothing. I am certain that it's simple to solve but my eyes are too addicted with this code!

If you can help me, I'll really appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: It's never a good idea to name 2 forms on the same page with the same name. Change the name of one of your forms

Comment: I tried this too and nothing! But thanks for your answer!